# issues sending SMS over ADB on a 'screenless' android system

Tags: adb, sms, permissions

I recently picked up a android based AP/WWAN device - [basically one of these](https://www.cnx-software.com/2022/08/04/inexpensive-snapdragon-410-4g-lte-wifi-modem-debian-11/). It has a Qualcomm Snapdragon 410 (MSM8916) and android 4.4.4 (as per `adb shell getprop ro.product.board` and `adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release`  in the form factor of a bulkier LTE dongle. There is no screen or way to interact with the machine directly. There's a limited web UI which dosen't expose much functionality so anything I need to do is likely over ADB. I'm not intending to reflash it to debian at the moment

I've checked it has the iSMS service as below. There's a [full list of supported services here](https://pastebin.com/HD3mph8W)

```
0       sip: [android.net.sip.ISipService]
1       phone: [com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony]
2       isms: [com.android.internal.telephony.ISms]
3       iphonesubinfo: [com.android.internal.telephony.IPhoneSubInfo]
```

I've tried using the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30224091/674571) to send an SMS - I've adjusted the service number appropriately and it seems to fail cause of permissions issues

```
geek@testbox31:~$ adb shell service call isms 2 s16 "com.android.mms" s16 "+55512345" s16 "+55523456" s16 "Test" i32 0 i32 0
Result: Parcel(
  0x00000000: ffffffff 00000062 00700055 00610064 '....b...U.p.d.a.'
  0x00000010: 00690074 0067006e 006d0020 00730065 't.i.n.g. .m.e.s.'
  0x00000020: 00610073 00650067 006f0020 0020006e 's.a.g.e. .o.n. .'
  0x00000030: 00630049 003a0063 004e0020 00690065 'I.c.c.:. .N.e.i.'
  0x00000040: 00680074 00720065 00750020 00650073 't.h.e.r. .u.s.e.'
  0x00000050: 00200072 00300032 00300030 006e0020 'r. .2.0.0.0. .n.'
  0x00000060: 0072006f 00630020 00720075 00650072 'o.r. .c.u.r.r.e.'
  0x00000070: 0074006e 00700020 006f0072 00650063 'n.t. .p.r.o.c.e.'
  0x00000080: 00730073 00680020 00730061 00610020 's.s. .h.a.s. .a.'
  0x00000090: 0064006e 006f0072 00640069 0070002e 'n.d.r.o.i.d...p.'
  0x000000a0: 00720065 0069006d 00730073 006f0069 'e.r.m.i.s.s.i.o.'
  0x000000b0: 002e006e 00450052 00450043 00560049 'n...R.E.C.E.I.V.'
  0x000000c0: 005f0045 004d0053 002e0053 00000000 'E._.S.M.S.......')
```

I've dumped out the permissions list - it'll be too large and noisy to post here, but you can find it [here on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DpAaQsxQ) and I can't find the android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS in the list

Is there any additional setup which will allow me to send SMSes from this device?